# How do HttpOnly cookies work with Javascript and authentication proxies?

Tags: javascript, cookies, openid-connect, httponly

I have a web application behind an OIDC reverse proxy -- in other words, when I visit this application I am redirected to my identity provider, I log in and my browser sets a cookie which is used on subsequent requests to prove that I have logged in.

This cookie has the [HttpOnly](https://owasp.org/www-community/HttpOnly) flag set, which I understand to be best practice to prevent XSS vulnerabilities being exploited by a malicious website.

However, as expected, Javascript within my application does not have access to the login cookie, so in my browser's console I see requests back to the application (trying to update dynamic content through both HTTP requests and websocket connections) being redirected to my identity provider (and blocked by CORS policy) since they do not have access to the login cookie.

- Does this mean that such an architecture cannot use Javascript to call back to the application?
- Is it common to disable the HTTPOnly flag to allow Javascript to work in such a case?
- My understanding is that Javascript from a malicious website at a different origin trying to access my application would be blocked by CORS anyway, so would keeping the HTTPOnly flag only help against attacks where the attacker managed to inject Javascript into my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean that such an architecture cannot used Javascript?

No. It means JS cannot read data from the cookie.

> I see requests back to the application (trying to update dynamic content through both HTTP requests and websocket connections) being redirected to my identity provider (and blocked by CORS policy) since they do not have access to the login cookie.

The CORS policy should not block requests because cookies are missing.

If a cookie is missing then it is probably because you are (a) getting your origins mixed up and that origin doesn't have a cookie or (b) you didn't enable the `credentials` [option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch#Parameters) for a cross-origin request.

> Is it common to disable the HTTPOnly flag to allow Javascript to work?

No.

> My understanding is that Javascript from a malicious website at a different origin trying to access my application would be blocked by CORS anyway, so would keeping the HTTPOnly flag only help against attacks where the attacker managed to inject Javascript into my application?

Yes. XSS attacks are so common that there are many tools to mitigate against them. This is one of them.

Comment: Sorry I updated the first bullet to `...use Javascript to call back to the application`. CORS is blocking the request because the login cookie isn't there for Javascript requests and so my OIDC proxy is triggering a redirect to my identity provider at a different origin. Would you agree then that with this architecture I have to choose between allowing Javascript callbacks to my application to update dynamic content and keeping the HttpOnly flag?

Comment: No, because that won't help. If you **don't** set the `credentials` option then JS will make the request  and it won't have credentials so it will be blocked. If you **do** set it then JS will make a preflight OPTIONS request to ask permission to make a cross-origin request with credentials and the preflight won't have credentials so it will be blocked.

Comment: Cool, and even if JS is not making a cross-origin request it needs to make a preflight OPTIONS request? because if not it sounds like removing the HttpOnly flag would be enough? I guess I could also disable auth only for OPTIONS requests (not sure on the security implications).

Comment: Final question I promise

Comment: If it's same origin then there's no CORS involved so no preflight request … and no need to remove the HttpOnly flag because that just stops JS from reading the cookie, not from making a request where it gets added on by the browser under the hood.